# No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0-alpha18-4804415 available for offline mode

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Using android 3.2 canary 18 and getting this error:

No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0-alpha18-4804415 available for offline mode.
and the jar file in https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha18-4804415/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha18-4804415.jar is deleted

how to fix this?

Comment: try disabling offline mode

Comment: it is disabled.the jar file in  maven repository is removed.

Answer (score 18):

Try doing this.Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler and the Command-line Options if your  text field contains --offline remove it

Comment: And how do I prevent this error from happening while in offline mode? (assuming I entered offline mode intentionally)

Answer (score 1):

**Disable offline mode**

> Step 1

Go to `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle`

> Step 2

Then **Uncheck** checkbox of `Offline Work`.

> Step 3

Click the `Apply` and `Ok` button.

> Step 4

Then click `File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files` and `Rebuild` the Project.

[image]

Comment: Strangely, I am getting this error after upgrading to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4' in 2020.3.1 Patch 4, and yet there is no such option in the gradle menu.